# Alternative of static abstract methods in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, static

I'm in a situation where I need all my child classes to implement a common abstract method of a parent class...**statically**. But apparently Java does not allow abstract static methods...

So, what is an alternative design of such implementation in Java? Below is the code that describes the situation I am in:

**Parent class**

```
public abstract class ParentFactory {
    /**
    * This is a factory class that provides static init method
    **/
    public abstract static void init();
}
```

**Child class**

```
public class ChildFactory extends ParentFactory {
    @Override
    public static void init() {
        // each child factory has own implementation of init
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

FYI, I am not asking why this is not valid in Java, I realise the concept of a static method, I know why it is not allowed in Java.

Instead I am asking for help with an alternative **design pattern** regarding my approach above. Thanks!

Comment: Possible, it will be better, if you'll make `init()` virtual, and will use `Factory` as singleton? Virtual method still can access static members.

Comment: Hi @KenBekov, would you be able to elaborate more on your idea please? (perhaps as an answer?) I would really like to hear great opinions about your suggested design.

Comment: I don't understand, for what purpose you do static `init()`. I guess, to init some kind of static members. But virtual method can do it as well. Usually, static method has a role of factory method. But your method returns nothing. So, there is not enough information, to suggest something specific.

Comment: @KenBekov Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I reviewed my code and realised I was incorrectly understanding Factory design pattern. You are absolutely correct about the point of using static init, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the understanding of the factory pattern. The typical answer to your question would be "use the factory pattern". Because in a factory you could call init on the concrete instance. If you are not using dependency injection and making use of loose coupling through inversion of control, a factory is typically implemented as a singleton. This is to get it from anywhere and there should only be one instance of a factory.

In short, if you want to initialize a factory because you want to subclass the factory (which doesn't make much sense IMHO), you need to create a factory that creates your factory.

Comment: Thanks you sir, you are exactly on point. After the question I took a close look at factory pattern and now am re-writing my code. Cheers!

Comment: Two things to add, IF you are using a framework like Spring (not saying you have to) you can use an init method to be called after an object is created. It gives you some Factory behavior without creating it as a Factory. Second, if you wanting to see a live example of a Factory you can see one here: https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=design-patterns-java-creational&author=bryan-hansen&name=design-patterns-java-creational-m5-factory&clip=0&mode=live

Answer (score 2):

If you create a static method, then that method can be accessed with the class itself, i.e. without creating an instance of that class. Therefore, a static method can't be abstract.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, plz see my question updated above.

Comment: This might not be the best possible solution, but you can make your static method in the parent class as an empty concrete method and your children classes can then, override it accordingly.

Comment: This actually won't work, as the OP noted. Static methods are not inheritable.

Answer (score 1):

If a method is static overriding it makes no sense because inheritance does not apply... that is the reason...

Static code is code related to a class and not to an object or an instance.

you need to modify your code...

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, plz see my question updated above.

Answer (score 1):

You might implement ChildFactory as singleton.

See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern